# How to show that a set $A$ is closed iff it is covered by a family $\mathcal{P}$ of open sets $U$, where $A \cap U$ is closed in $U$?

Tags: general-topology

How to show that a set $A$ is closed if and only if it is covered by a family $\mathcal{P}$ of open sets, where $A \cap U$ is closed in $U$ for each open set $U$ in $\mathcal{P}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? The $\implies$ direction is obvious from the definition of the subspace topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be the space. For the easy direction, note that $X$ itself is an open set.

The other direction isn’t true as stated: Ink’s answer provides a counterexample. It becomes true, however, if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ rather than just of $A$. In that case suppose that $x\in X\setminus A$. There is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $x\in U$, and $U\setminus A$ is then an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $A$. It follows that $X\setminus A$ is open and hence that $A$ is closed.

Comment: thank you very much. Is $U\backslash A$ closed in $U$ or $X$? Is this follows from the assumption that $U \cap A$ is closed in $U$?

Comment: @LJR: $U\setminus A$ is **open** (in $X$), and yes, this follows from the assumption that $U\cap A$ is closed in $U$.

Comment: thank you very much. Is $U\backslash A$ open in $U$? Can the condition $U \cap A $ is open in $U$ be replaced by the condition: $U \cap A $ is open in $X$?

Comment: @LJR: Since $U$ is open in $X$, a subset of $U$ that is open in $U$ is automatically open in $X$ as well, so $U\setminus A$ is open in both $U$ and $X$. $U\cap A$ is **closed** in $U$; did you mean $U\setminus A$ in the second question?

Comment: thank you very much. I mean could we replace "a subset $A$ of $X$ is closed if and only if $X$ is covered by a family $\mathcal{P}$ of open sets, where $A \cap U$ is closed in $U$ for each open set $U$ in $\mathcal{P}$" by "a subset $A$ of $X$ is closed if and only if $X$ is covered by a family $\mathcal{P}$ of open sets, where $A \cap U$ is closed in $X$ for each open set $U$ in $\mathcal{P}$"?

Comment: @LJR: You can’t reasonably expect $A\cap U$ to be closed in $X$: in general the intersection of a closed set with an open set isn’t closed (though of course it can be in some cases).

Comment: @LJR: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This is false.  Consider $A = (0, 1]$ and $\mathcal{P} = \{(0, 2)\}$.

Note that $\implies$ is true by taking $X = U$.